# Dynamically store data in the columns of pandas dataframe from numpy arrays being generated from “for loop”

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, iterator

```
in[31]: day_1_variable.shape
```

```
out[31]: (241, 241)
```

This is the dictionary of 10 numpy arrays with 241 * 241 (rows * columns)

```
df_dictionary = {'arrays_to_iterate': {'day_1': day_1_variable,
                                   'day_2': day_2_variable, 
                                   'day_3': day_3_variable,
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .

                                   'day_10': day_10_variable}}
```

```
day = 10
for days in np.arange(1,day+1):
    numpy_array_to_iterate = df_dictionary ['arrays_to_iterate']['day_'+str(days)+'_rf']
       
    variable_value_array=np.zeros((0),dtype='float')          ## empty array of variable value created
    for i in np.arange(numpy_array_to_iterate.shape[0]):      ## iterating array rows 
        for j in np.arange(numpy_array_to_iterate.shape[1]):  ## iterating array column  
            variable_value_at_specific_point=numpy_array_to_iterate[i][j]

            variable_value_array=np.append(variable_value_array,variable_value_at_specific_point) ## values filled in array


    df_xyz = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in np.arange(1,day+1):
        col_name = 'variable_day_' + str(i)
        df_xyz.loc[:, col_name] = variable_value_array
df_xyz
```

I want to store the array data of each day in column of pandas dataframe having value of the variable for each corresponding day

But the output that I am getting here has value of last day in each column

```
          variable_day_1    variable_day_2  ........... variable_day_10
0         0.0625            0.0625          ........... 0.0625  
1         0.0625            0.0625          ........... 0.0625  
2         0.0625            0.0625          ........... 0.0625  
3         0.0625            0.0625          ........... 0.0625  
4         0.0625            0.0625          ........... 0.0625  
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

58076     0.0000            0.0000          ........... 0.0000  
58077     0.0000            0.0000          ........... 0.0000  
58078     0.0000            0.0000          ........... 0.0000  
58079     0.0000            0.0000          ........... 0.0000  
58080     0.0000            0.0000          ........... 0.0000  
58081 rows × 10 columns
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Numpy [`stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) over the dictionary values (this will give you a Numpy array with shape `(10, 241, 241)`) then use [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to modify the shape to `(10,58081)` follow by transpose, to place the days as columns. Next, convert to a Pandas dataframe and fix the column names using the dictionary keys.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#setup
np.random.seed(12345)
df_dictionary = {}
days = {f'day_{d}': np.random.rand(241,241).round(2) for d in range(1,11)}
df_dictionary['arrays_to_iterate'] = days
print(df_dictionary)

#code
all_days = np.stack(list(df_dictionary['arrays_to_iterate'].values())).reshape(10, -1).T
df = pd.DataFrame(all_days)
df.columns = df_dictionary['arrays_to_iterate'].keys()

print(df)
```

Ouput from *df_dictionary*

```py
{'arrays_to_iterate':
    {'day_1':
        array(
        [[0.93, 0.32, 0.18, ..., 0.62, 0.89, 0.78],
        [0.72, 0.31, 0.36, ..., 0.5 , 0.89, 0.38],
        ...,
        [0.36, 0.62, 0.77, ..., 0.03, 0.57, 0.04],
        [0.02, 0.07, 0.66, ..., 0.62, 0.5 , 0.04]]),
    'day_2': array(
        [[0.14, 0.13, 0.91, ..., 0.06, 0.72, 0.93],
        [0.13, 0.02, 0.09, ..., 0.39, 0.72, 0.13],
    ...
```

Output from *df*

```py
       day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  day_5  day_6  day_7  day_8  day_9  day_10
0       0.93   0.14   0.06   0.10   0.01   0.66   0.67   0.18   0.93    0.40
1       0.32   0.13   0.81   0.57   0.23   0.60   0.48   0.07   0.08    0.32
2       0.18   0.91   0.95   0.27   0.36   0.11   0.25   0.71   0.24    0.44
3       0.20   0.51   0.52   0.62   0.09   0.31   0.19   0.78   0.83    0.58
4       0.57   0.14   0.89   0.51   0.67   0.29   0.48   0.95   0.36    0.97
...      ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...
58076   0.98   0.20   0.54   0.96   0.89   0.24   0.05   0.81   0.35    0.57
58077   0.53   0.96   0.04   0.60   0.16   0.38   0.83   0.49   0.28    0.02
58078   0.62   0.50   0.74   0.67   0.43   0.30   0.91   0.68   0.15    0.43
58079   0.50   0.11   0.57   0.42   0.85   0.97   0.86   0.60   0.75    0.33
58080   0.04   0.74   0.74   0.94   0.98   0.35   0.52   0.12   0.47    0.53

[58081 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thanks for your time @n1colas.m.